# Mongo refusing connections after system shut it down for RAM outage

Tags: mongodb

according to kern.log, system killed mongo due to having no more RAM available (server has 8GB)

```
Mar 15 18:06:21 ns504049 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 10532 (mongod) score 0 or sacrifice child
Mar 15 18:06:21 ns504049 kernel: Killed process 10532 (mongod) total-vm:2556716kB, anon-rss:26968kB, file-rss:0kB
```

It also killed my screen process.

Now `mongod service start` will work, but mongo will get `errno:111 Connection refused`

i had `mongod.lock` in both data/db/ and var/lib/mongodb, removed both and issued `mongod --repair` every time, it claimed success but I'm still getting the same error when trying to connect .

Since i tought it may be that the old process using the `27017` port i tried to do `mongod --shutdown` but it will output:

```
There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db
```

but my mongod.conf has `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`...

I even tried:

```
$sudo service mongod start
mongod start/running, process 17958
$service mongod status
mongod stop/waiting
$mongod --shutdown
There doesn't seem to be a server running with dbpath: /data/db
```

why is it looking for that `dbpath` ?

note: i'm running everything as root
The only way i manged to at least look into the db is using `mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb` in a `byobu` window and opening `mongo` console in another

Comment: `ps ax | grep mongo`

Comment: not quite the talkative guy huh? :P
anyways thanks for helping, here's my output: `28511 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mongo`

Comment: this is not a chat :P. well then it is most probably not running. what is in the log after you try to `service mongod start` it?

Comment: well you sure got a point on the chat argument :p Anyways,  heres' the output: `mongod start/running, process 32271` , i'm hella new to linux and bash commands, is the 32271 the pid? because issuing `kill 32271` gives me a `No such process` ...

Comment: I am talking about the mongo log ... it could be  `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` (it is in my ubuntu), or in the `/var/lib/mongodb`. You'll have to find that yourself. Get few last lines - those should help you make sense of what is going on. Another place to look is the system log `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog` ...

Comment: `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` stopped loggin when server crashed yesterday, with the last lines being queries, while `/var/lib/mongodb/` has no log file... looking into my `etc/mongod.conf` file, it should be logging in the first location... but as i said there's nothing past the crash date

Comment: That looks like mongod can't write to the log file (my last guess). What are the permissions on it?

Comment: `root@ns504049:/var/log/mongodb# ls -l mongod.log` outputs 
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 207662604 Mar 15 18:03 mongod.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing owner of your logfile to that mongodb runs under. In ubuntu its `mongodb`.

So `chown mongodb /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`.

Comment: that made logging work again, thanks!
It also pointed me towards the answer: one of my database files had `root` as owner, therefore mongo couldn't open it.
As for **why** this ownership changed or why the crash may be linked to it... i have no idea... I you can give me any insight, i'm gonna select this as the answer in a minute anyways, and thanks :)

Comment: No probs. Change of ownership was probably not caused by the crash. I'd say those two things are not linked at all. Rather something happened between last start of mongod and the crash, which changed the ownership. Once the database files are open, mongo does not need permissions to modify those. So this could've gone unnoticed for quite some time.

Comment: _"Once the database files are open, mongo does not need permissions to modify those. So this could've gone unnoticed for quite some time."_ This just gave me the chills, brb gonna check a lot of code :P